# Bayes' theorem: how frequently is the medical test correct?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose that 1 in 3 people showing symptoms of dry cough, fatigue (tiredness) 
and fever have COVID19.There is a test for COVID-19 that gives a positive result 98.5% 
of the time when given to someone with the disease. When given to someone without the disease.
80% of the time it gives a negative result.

1. What is the probability that a randomly selected person showing symptoms of dry cough, fatigue (tiredness) and fever has COVID-19 if the test returns a positive result?
2. What is the probability that a randomly selected person showing symptoms of dry cough, fatigue (tiredness) and fever does not have COVID-19 if the test returns a negative result?

---

I approached the problem following way but got stuck
Let +ve denote the people who test positive. 
And covid denote people who actually have covid.
Now from the given statements we can say that 
P(+ve | covid) = .985 -- Means Given a person has 
covid the probability that the test result will be +ve is .985 
P(-ve | non-covid) = .8
P(covid | symptoms) = 1/3

Now the Q1. asks to find out P(+ve | symptoms)
P(+ve | symptoms ) = P(symptoms | +ve) x P(+ve) / P(symptoms)

Now the test gives +ve 98.5% of time for one with covid and
when given to somone without covid it gives +ve 20% of the time.
P(+ve | non-covid)  =.2  Dont know how to proceed further

Comment: Question 2's answer is $99.07\%.$  More [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3971235/21813).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the first questions, the second is very similiar.

$$p(\text{covid}|\text{positive}) = \frac{p(\text{positive}|\text{covid})p(\text{covid})}{p(\text{positive}|\text{covid})p(\text{covid})+ p(\text{positive}|\text{not covid})p(\text{not covid})} =\\
\frac{0.985\times0.33}{0.985\times0.33 + 0.2\times0.66} \sim 70\%
$$

This is why doctors make patients take more tests if a test is known to give false positives.
See [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xX04.jpg) for a geometric interpretation for this kind of problems: think about plugging a number of random event at top.

Bye

Comment: in the above you have assumed that p(covid) = 0.33 . Although the question mention its the probabilty of people showing **symptoms** + **covid**. So there could be people who have covid and not have symptoms. so **p(covid) = p(covid with symptoms) + P(covid without symptoms).** so what I understand is** p(covid with symptoms) = .33**. Correct me

Comment: yes of course. for brevity sake i write $p(\text{covid})$ and $p(\text{not covid})$ basically meaning $p(\text{symptomatic person has covid})$ and $p(\text{symptomatic person does not have covid})$. we have no informations about asymptomatic covid here @nishaaunty