# Finding the probability that a person is positive given a negative test?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

Given the problem of a patient taking a test for a disease where having the disease is denoted by X and the a positive test is denoted by Y,

- the rate of occurrence of the disease in the general population is 1%
- The odds of getting tested positive is 90% if you have the disease
- the probability of a false positive  is 3%

is it appropriate to solve the following through rearranging the total probability

$P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|Not B)P(Not B)$

Into

$P(A|B) = (P(A) -P(A|B)P(B))/P(Not B)$

and then getting P(B) from the total probability

$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B| Not A)P(Not A)$

then given B is binary P(Not B) from

$1 = P(B) + P(Not B)$

and getting P(A|B) from Bayes

$P(A|B) = = P(A)P(B|A)/P(B)$

and then substituting that all back into the first equation to get the result

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: This is hard to read, as you seem to switch notation from $X,Y$ to $A,B$ without explanation.  In any case, this problem (with different numbers) has been asked over and over again on this site.  Just do a simple search.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740647/bayes-theorem-disease-probability) is one duplicate for example.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "probability" in place of ["odds"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)?

Comment: Refer to the probability tree at the top of, and scroll down to "false omission rate" in, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4319216/21813).

Answer (score 0):

We have by Bayes' rule

$$P(X|Y^c)=\frac{P(Y^c|X)P(X)}{P(Y^c|X)P(X)+P(Y^c|X^c)P(X^c)}.$$

Your setup has $P(X)=0.01,P(Y|X)=0.9,P(Y|X^c)=0.03.$